# How to edit pills of Kendo UI Multiselect

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, multi-select

With the Kendo UI multiselect, they have built in pill containers... you can specify specific tagTemplates, but this just changes what is inside the pill container, not the pill itself.

I am wondering if anyone would know how to customize the actual pill of a selected item.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS styling of your choice on the appropriate selector, i.e.

```
.k-multiselect li.k-button {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: deeppink;
}
```

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/AyEKE

**Edit based on comment**
CSS does not have a parent selector to go *up* from the tagTemplate to the parent `<li>`, to which the style needs to be applied, as applying the style to the content/tagTemplate itself does not encompass the whole tag.  It can be done using javascript, though.

I've updated the example to attach to the change event of the Multiselect to execute some javascript to apply a background colour to the *parent* `<li>` of the selected items based on some arbitrary value of the item.  In my example, I added the CompanyName to the tagTemplate a data value and my javascript triggers on that to apply a different colour based on the name.

Updated the tagTemplate to include the CompanyName of the items:

```
tagTemplate:  '<span data-companyname="#:data.CompanyName#"...
```

And added a change event handler to the multiselect that finds the parent node and applies a style:

```
change: function (e) {
                    var selectedTags = $(".k-multiselect li.k-button");
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedTags.length; i++) {
                      var tag = $(selectedTags[i]);
                      var item = $(tag.find("span.selected-value"));
                      if (item.data("companyname") === "Alfreds Futterkiste") {
                        tag.css({ "background-color": "deeppink" });
                      }
                      if (item.data("companyname") === "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados") {
                        tag.css({ "background-color": "green" });
                      }
                      // ...
                    }
                  }
```

Now, this is not necessarily the best way to implement the javascript, but I do believe that you *have* to use javascript.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the class names for the kendo multiselect pills and couldn't find them anywhere. However, how might I access these if I want each pill to be a different color based on the color value of the item inside the multiselect.

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS does not have a parent selector, which you would need to select the parent li of the tagTemplate to set the background-color. It can be done using javascript though. I've updated the answer a bit.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed. I added a change function similar to yours, but I have a dynamic list of people (could be very different every time) so I grab the new tag in question (that you just clicked on to be added), then do another loop to loop through all people in the multiselect to match up names, then when a match is found, set their tag color to their selected color :)

Comment: Tyler - regarding your first comment, the class names for any kendo ui elements can easily be found by opening the developer tools in your browser and inspecting the elements on the page.

Comment: What if there is more then 1 multiselect Elements and i need to change color only specific's only 1 multiselect ? You code seems like applied for all multi selectors

Comment: @Naitik, use a more specific CSS selector(i.e. using the id) on the style for the specific MultiSelect. Example with 2 MultiSelcts and 2 styles: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/IVEJERAW